# Margin left for a input type text

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, margin

i'm a french begginer (so excuse the fact that some part of it are in french, if it's a problem i can translate, also i know my code can be more clean so if you have any idea dont hesitate!).
I'm coding a form for a project and i would like to align all my text like this :

[image]

but my page look like this for the moment :

[image]

```css
fieldset {
  width: 900px;
}

em {
  color: red;
}

#demande {
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

strong {
  color: #C1D58D;
}

input {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

````html
<fieldset>
  <legend><b>INFORMATIONS PERSONNELLES</b></legend>
  <form method="get">
    <label for "Nom">Nom<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nom" id="text" required />
  </form>
  </br>
  </br>
  <form method="get">
    <label for "Prénom">Prénom<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="text" name="Prénom" id="text" required />
  </form>
  </br>
  </br>
  <form method="get">
    <form method="get">
      <label><strong> Votre sexe</strong><em>*</em> :</label> </br>
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Fille" /> <label for="Fille">Fille</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Garçon" /> <label for="Garçon">Garçon</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Autre" /> <label for="Autre">Autre</label>
    </form>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label> Année<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="number" name="Année" id="Année" placeholder="Exemple : 1987" />
  </form>
  </br>
  </br>
  <form method="get">
    <label for "pays"> Pays<em>*</em> :</label>
    <select name="pays" id="pays" required>
      <optgroup label="Europe">
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="espagne">Espagne</option>
        <option value="royaume-uni">Royaume-Uni</option>
        <option value="italie">Italie</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Amérique">
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="etats-unis">États-Unis</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Asie">
        <option value="chine">Chine</option>
        <option value="japon">Japon</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    </br>
    </br>
  </form>
  <h3>Les champs marqués par <em>*</em> sont obligatoires</h3>
</fieldset>
</br>
<form method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Annuler" />
  <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
</form>

```
````

i know i could creat an id for every  then edit it with css but i was wondering if there was a best way to do it (a more efficient way)

Comment: You may want to use CSS classes or flexbox.

Comment: easiest way to perfectly align this is with the use of CSS-Grid

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is the use of CSS-Grid. I removed the form tags so that all elements are direct children of the fieldset.

As such I can declared `fieldset { display: grid; }` to apply the grid.
Next I apply a 2 column layout where the first column takes as much space as needed and the second column the remaining space with: `fieldset { grid-template-columns: min-content auto;`.
To space the elements apart, you can use the `grid-gap`-property.

```css
fieldset {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

em {
  color: red;
}

fieldset h3 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><b>INFORMATIONS PERSONNELLES</b></legend>
    <label for "Nom">Nom<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nom" id="text" required />
    <label for "Prénom">Prénom<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="text" name="Prénom" id="text" required />
    <label><strong> Votre sexe</strong><em>*</em> :</label>   
    <div class="radio-group">
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Fille" /> <label for="Fille">Fille</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Garçon" /> <label for="Garçon">Garçon</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Autre" /> <label for="Autre">Autre</label>
    </div>
    <label> Année<em>*</em> :</label>
    <input type="number" name="Année" id="Année" placeholder="Exemple : 1987" />
    <label for "pays"> Pays<em>*</em> :</label>
    <select name="pays" id="pays" required>
      <optgroup label="Europe">
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="espagne">Espagne</option>
        <option value="royaume-uni">Royaume-Uni</option>
        <option value="italie">Italie</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Amérique">
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="etats-unis">États-Unis</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Asie">
        <option value="chine">Chine</option>
        <option value="japon">Japon</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  <h3>Les champs marqués par <em>*</em> sont obligatoires</h3>
</fieldset>
<form method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Annuler" />
  <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```